# add/remove buttons in java SWT app, while app is running.

Tags: java, swt

I am writing a application for manipulating a custom sqlite DB. 
DB is quite complicated, it has tree like structure.

```
main
--->operator1
------>name
------>address
--->operator2
------>name
------>address
------>tariffs
---------->name
---------->price
```

I need to have something like a 'path' in order to easily browse through the table and edit stuff... My data is organized as SWT Table. I have SWT.MouseDoubleClick listener attached to it. I intent to 'step into' my operator data by double clicking on a particular table row. The problem is, how to get back to the 'main view', I need some sort of navigation for that purpose.
My current idea is to create a container and add necessary buttons into it. Similar to

[nautilus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiOZG.png)

Notice, the path is created as consecutive buttons, aligned horizontally:

```
mentis -> Dropbox -> Photos
```

The big question is how to do that ;)

I am able to create a button and add it to may container, however this works only when application starts. I don't know how to add buttons to my container when the app is running.

In my main class I have sth like this:

```
    Composite pathBarContainer = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    pathBarContainer.setSize(shell.getBounds().width, 20);
    pathBarContainer.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));
    GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL);
    gridData.horizontalSpan = 3;
    pathBarContainer.setLayoutData(gridData);

    pathBar = new PathBar(pathBarContainer, shell, contentProvider);
    pathBar.getPathBar();
```

this is my PathBar class:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class PathBar {

Composite parent;
Composite pathBar;
Shell mainShell;
ContentProvider contentProvider;
Button mainButton;
Button nextButton;

public PathBar(Composite parent_in, Shell mainShell_in, ContentProvider cp) {

    parent = parent_in;
    mainShell = mainShell_in;
    contentProvider = cp;


    pathBar = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER_DOT);
    //pathBar.setSize(100, 300);
    pathBar.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, true));

    mainButton = new Button(pathBar, SWT.PUSH);
    mainButton.setText("main");

}

public Composite getPathBar() {



    return pathBar;
}

public void addMainButton() {
    mainButton = new Button(pathBar, SWT.PUSH);
    mainButton.setText("main");
    pathBar.redraw();
    //parent.redraw();
    //mainShell.redraw();
}

public void addButton() {
    nextButton = new Button(pathBar, SWT.PUSH);
    nextButton.setText("sth");
    pathBar.redraw();
    parent.redraw();
    System.out.println("addButton");
}
}
```

Methods addMainButton() and addButton() are supposed to be run from eventHandler... attached to my SWT table...

How to solve this ? 
Pls help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell it to redo your layout after you add buttons.

```
pathBar.layout(true);
```